# currvita, multibib & scrbook - multibib does not work

Tags: bibliographies, multibib, subdividing

I need a list of own publications inside a c.v. which is an appendix to my actual document. I'm using `currvita` for a simple c.v. and I'm trying to employ `multibib` as suggested in the `currvita` manual to get the publication list like this (my `.bib` file is called `bibliography.bib`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[ManyBibs]{currvita}
\newcites{cv}{Publikationen}
\bibliographystyle{hep}
\bibliographystylecv{hep}

\begin{document}
%lots of stuff and citations
\bibliobgraphy{bibliography}

\begin{cv}{}
\begin{cvlist}{Publikationen}
 \nocitecv{cite1,cite2,cite3}
 \item \bibliographycv{bibliography}
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv} 
\end{document}
```

The normal bibliography works without a problem and there is no actual error when compiling, but a warning

```
No file cv.bbl
```

and the publication list is not created.

Why is it trying to look for `cv.bbl`? Or: why is it not created?

Comment: How are you compiling your document? If your document is test.tex you have to compile like this: `(pdf)latex test` + `bibtex test` + `bibtex cv` + `(pdf)latex test` + `(pdf)latex test`.

Comment: My bad. I've been trusting my editor to much.
"Solution" is below. Shall I leave this question for the benefit of others or rather delete it?

Comment: @Gonzalo: That's been amazingly synchronous. You're of course right, I was missing the 'bibtex cv' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Stupid me.
My tex-Editor (Kile) does not automatically generate the `bbl` files from the `aux` in this special situation. Manually issuing `bibtex cv.aux` has been sufficient.