# My multi bibliography appears empty (using multibib package)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran, multibib

My bibliography (actually 4 different ones) is empty. If I try only one, with normal bibtex, it works.

I have read the multibib package manual pdf file. I have read the thread [currvita, multibib & scrbook - multibib does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/currvita-multibib-scrbook-multibib-does-not-work#new-answer?newreg=d8241cd8a116455296c3109bd1ab756e) and so many others. I had the same problem - no .bbl - file. Now i have bbl but it says I have no citations, which is not true.

Extracts of my cv.tex file:

```
\newcites{articles}{Artigos em Congressos}
\newcites{papers}{Papers em Journals}
\newcites{books}{Livros ou Capítulos de Livros}
\newcites{posters}{Posters}
\bibliographystylearticles{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystylepapers{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystylebooks{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyleposters{IEEEtran}
.....
\nocitearticles{*}
\nocitepapers{*}
\nocitebooks{*}
\nociteposters{*}
\bibliographyarticles{articles}                   % Artigos em conf.
\bibliographypapers{papers}                   % Papers em Journals
\bibliographybooks{books}                   % Livros
\bibliographyposters{posters}             %posters
```

I can open all my bib files in Jabref and none gives errors. My log file:

```
The top-level auxiliary file: cv.aux 
The style file: IEEEtran.bst Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 3 of file cv.aux : \bibstyle : {IEEEtran} 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 4 of file cv.aux : \bibstyle : {IEEEtran} 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 5 of file cv.aux : \bibstyle : {IEEEtran} 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
I found no \citation commands---while reading file cv.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file cv.aux
```

I have IEEEtran.bst in the same folder as cv.tex

I am doing in terminal exactly what page 4 of the pdf manual of multibib says:

```
latex cv.tex
bibtex cv.tex
bibtex posters.aux
bibtex articles.aux
bibtex papers.aux
bibtex books.aux
latex cv.tex
latex cv.tex
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

OK, here it is a minimal example of the tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{url}

\newcites{articles}{Artigos em Congressos}
\newcites{papers}{Papers em Journals}
\newcites{books}{Livros ou Capítulos de Livros}
\newcites{posters}{Posters}
\bibliographystylearticles{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystylepapers{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystylebooks{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyleposters{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Habilitações Literárias}
-----
\subsection{Publicações}
\nocitearticles{*}
\nocitepapers{*}
\nocitebooks{*}
\nociteposters{*}
\bibliographyarticles{articles}                   
\bibliographypapers{papers}                  
\bibliographybooks{books}                  
\bibliographyposters{posters}                  
\end{document}
```

And the bib files:

> articles.bib

```
@InProceedings{Malta-methodologies,
  Title                    = {State of the Art on Methodologies for the Development of a Metadata Application Profile},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A. A.},
  Booktitle                = {Comunications in Computer and Information Sciences},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Editor                   = {J. M. Dodero, M. Palomo-Duarte, P. Karampiperis},
  Pages                    = {61–73},
  Publisher                = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
  Volume                   = {343},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2012.10.23}
}

@InProceedings{CuradoMalta2013,
  Title                    = {Me4{DCAP V}0.1: A method to develop {D}ublin {C}ore {A}pplication {P}rofiles},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A. A.},
  Booktitle                = {Proceedings of the 17th International Conference on Electronic Publishing - Mining the Digital Information Networks},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Editor                   = {N. Lavesson, P. Linde, P. Polydoratou},
  Pages                    = {33 - 44},
  Publisher                = {IOS Press},

  Doi                      = {10.3233/978-1-61499-270-7-33},
  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2013.06.13},
  Url                      = {http://ebooks.iospress.nl/publication/33460}
}

@InProceedings{CuradoMalta2013c,
  Title                    = {A method for the development of {D}ublin {C}ore {A}pplication {P}rofiles ({M}e{4DCAP V}0.2): detailed description},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A. A.},
  Booktitle                = {International Conference on Dublin Core and Metadata Applications},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Organization             = {Dublin Core Metadata Initiative},
  Pages                    = {90--103},

  Conference               = {International Conference on Dublin Core and Metadata Applications},
  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2013.08.19},
  Url                      = {http://dcevents.dublincore.org/IntConf/dc-2013/paper/view/178/81}
}
```

> papers.bib

```
@Article{CuradoMalta2014,
  Title                    = {A panoramic view on {M}etadata {A}pplication {P}rofiles of the last decade},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A.A.},
  Journal                  = {International Journal of Metadata, Semantics and Ontologies},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {58-73},
  Volume                   = {9},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2013.09.16}
}

@Article{CuradoMalta2013b,
  Title                    = {Me4{DCAP V}0.1: A method for the development of {D}ublin {Co}re {A}pplication {P}rofiles},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A. A.},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Information Systems \& Use},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {161-171},
  Volume                   = {33},

  Doi                      = {10.3233/ISU-130706},
  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2013.09.16},
  Url                      = {\url{http://iospress.metapress.com/content/t04963284412u236/?p=77f967e6089549a1b0f61a689452e804&pi=11}}
}

@Article{CuradoMalta2013d,
  Title                    = {State of the Art on Methodologies for the Development of a Metadata Application Profile},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A. A.},
  Journal                  = {International Journal of Metadata, Semantics and Ontologies},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {332-341},
  Volume                   = {8}
}

@Article{CuradoMalta2014a,
  Title                    = {Social and {S}olidarity {E}conomy {W}eb {I}nformation {S}ystems: {S}tate of the {A}rt and an {I}nteroperability {F}ramework},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A.A. and Parente, C.},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Electronic Commerce in Organisations},
  Year                     = {2014},

  Month                    = {January-March},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {35-52},
  Volume                   = {12},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2013.09.26}
}
```

> books.bib

```
@PhdThesis{CuradoMalta2014,
  Title                    = {Contributo metodológico  para o desenvolvimento de perfis de aplicação no contexto da Web Semântica},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M.},
  School                   = {Universidade do Minho},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Month                    = {Julho},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.07}
}

@InCollection{ecommerce,
  Title                    = {E-commerce and the Web of Data},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A.A.},
  Booktitle                = {Encyclopedia of E-Commerce Development, Implementation, and Management },
  Publisher                = {IGI Global},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Editor                   = {Lee, I.},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2012.01.14}
}

@InCollection{MaltaWIS-SSE,
  Title                    = {Social and Solidarity Economy Web Information Systems: State of the Art},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, A.A.},
  Booktitle                = {Social e-Entreprise: Value Creation through ICT},
  Publisher                = {IGI Global},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Chapter                  = {1},
  Editor                   = {Vidal, A. and Torres, T.},
  Pages                    = {1-16},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2012.01.14}
}
```

> posters.bib

```
@Article{POSTER-ECRM,
  Title                    = {A Design Science Approach: A method for the development of Dublin Core Application Profiles},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, Ana Alice},
  Journal                  = {12th European Conference on Research Methodology for Business and Management Studies},
  Year                     = {2013},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.13}
}

@Article{POSTER-El-PUB,
  Title                    = {On the need to develop an interoperability framework for Social and Solidarity Economy Web Based Information Systems},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, Mariana and Baptista, Ana Alice},
  Journal                  = {16th International Conference on Electronic Publishing - Social Shaping of Digital Publishing: Exploring the interplay between Culture and Technology.},
  Year                     = {2012},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.13}
}

@Article{POSTER-APSI,
  Title                    = {Contributing to the definition of a method for the development of Dublin Core Application Profiles},
  Author                   = {Curado Malta, M. and Baptista, Ana Alice and Parente, Cristina},
  Journal                  = {13ª Conferência da Associação Portuguesa de Sistemas de Informação},
  Year                     = {2013},

  Owner                    = {mariana},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.13}
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, you might be much better of using `biblatex` for that task.

Comment: Did you cite anything? You can use `\nocite{*}` to include all available entries.

Comment: you can see that i \nocitearticles(*) and so on,  on  the .tex extract file.

I don't have biblatex installed. Never hear of it. bibtex always worked with me.....i just look at the info of biblatex and understand that is a more modern one and taht i need to change my bib files. that is out of question since they are huge!

Comment: You haven't shown a minimal working example testable for us. You use different cites, but non for the main `cv.tex`. That does not include any cite commands, according to the BibTeX-log.  I guess it is just a typo as the log file is correct, but you need to run bibtex on `cv.aux`.

Comment: OK, I have changed the post with example testable. I do apreciate your help.

Comment: In the meantime, thes discussion has moved to [LaTeX community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=26291&p=89855#p89854).

Answer (score 1):

Give the url as is, do not enclose it with `\url` with `IEEEtran.bst`.

`Url = {http://iospress.metapress.com/content/t04963284412u236/?p=77f967e6089549a1b0f61a689452e804&pi=11}`

Turns out that there was a local copy of `multibib.sty` dating back to 2003 that also prevented compiling.

Comment: Remember to delete your auxiliary files first.

Comment: OK. I took \url out. And deleted all files but .tex and .bib. The "Publicações" sub section continues empty and the errors are exactly the same.

Comment: Please add which errors you got to the question. Appart from that one entry with the url, preventing the document from compiling, everything works like a charm.

Comment: I had to add author and title to your MWE, fixing the one entry it works. Please verify, that the minimal example works for you as well. It is possible, that the cause is somewhere else. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/ <- following that algorithm, you will soon find the cause and specify the question.

Comment: What does MWE means?

Comment: @MarianaCuradoMalta Minimal working example.